# Why is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n I(x - x_n)$ not continuous when $x = x_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

> Let $I(x) =
>   \begin{cases} 
>       \hfill 0    \hfill & x \leq 0 \\
>       \hfill 1 \hfill & x > 0
>   \end{cases}$.
>
> If $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of distinct points of $(a, b)$, and if $\sum\lvert c_n \rvert$ converges, the series $$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n I(x - x_n)  \text{, where } (a \leq x \leq b)$$ converges uniformly, and $f$ is continuous for every $x \neq x_n$, but $f$ is not continuous when $x = x_n$.

If $x = x_n$, then every term is $0$, which is a continuous function. Why is the claim that it's not continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because at I(0) the limit from either side is different- I(x) is said to be discontinuous at this point - from the right hand side we have 1 , from the left hand side we have 0.

Comment: Ahhh, I can't believe I didn't realize this. Thank you!

Comment: No worries , all the best.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $x \in [a,b]$, and let $S_x = \{ n \in \mathbb N \, | \, x > x_n \}$. Then the function $f$ can be described as $f(x) = \sum_{n \in S_x} c_n$. This is always a convergent series by assumption, but its value is not a continuous parameter of $x$ ; it admits a discontinuity of "jump type" ($\lim_{x \to c^+}$ and $\lim_{x \to c^-}$ exist but are not equal) and you can check that the difference between these two limits at $x_N$ is precisely $c_N$. This is essentially because if you go through the interval $[a,b]$ from left to right, you pick a jump at each $x_n$ of size $c_n$.

In particular, $f$ is continuous at $x_n$ if and only if $c_n = 0$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

Also,
it is *not* true that
every term is zero,
only the terms with
$x \le x_n$.
If
$x > x_n$,
then
the term is
$c_n$.